# $.ajax call and getting/scrolling to top of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have a div that is populated by an ajax call. I'm guessing that I can't scrollTop() to the div because the dom has the height as 0.

How can I dynamically get the top of the div and scroll (animate) to the top everytime the content is loaded?

```
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: 'content/'+u+'/this.content.php',
        data: { 'data-set-id' : t},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(e) {
            $('#div .content').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).html(e).fadeIn();                  

            });
            // scroll to top of the populated div
        },
        error: function(e) {
            // error 
        }
    }); // ajax
```

Comment: Dom is always updated after changes, so you can use standard way of doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does

```
$("#div").animate({scrollTop: "0px"});
```

not work?

Anyone else who stumbles across this, here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2z3fx3j5/1/

```
<body>
    <div>Hello</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: "1000px"}, 2000);
    $("body").animate({scrollTop: "0px"}, 2000);
});

div {
    bordeR: solid 1px black;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

Comment: What is the div that you want to scroll in?

Comment: We can't help you unless you tell us what the result html looks like, I don't know what you are naming your div when you replace the entire content's html with the result from your ajax call...

Comment: You're right. I was initiating on the wrong div, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code in the success callback to scroll to the top of the div after the content is loaded.

`var stop =  $('#div .content').scrollTop();
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: stop }, 'slow');`

i hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't work at the moment. The scroll is an inner page div with overflow-y: scroll;

Answer (score 0):

[**Mutation-Observers**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the one way to handle the issue in hand, Add the following code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
var target = $("#div .content");
// Create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function( mutations ) {
   mutations.forEach(function( mutation ) {
   var newNodes = mutation.addedNodes; // DOM NodeList
if( newNodes !== null ) { 
    // If there are new nodes added
      $('#div .content')animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow'); 
      }
   });    
});

// Configuration of the observer:
var config = { 
attributes: true, 
childList: true, 
characterData: true 
};

// Pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
success: function(e) {
            $('#div .content').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).html(e).fadeIn();

             $('html, body').animate({
                          scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
              }, 1000);                  

            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by resetting contents of the DOM before $.ajax

```
$('#div .content').empty(); 
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    // ...
});
```

or

```
$('#div .content').html('loading...');
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    // ...
});
```

This answer is seven years late in 2017 :)